# Value of type 'Express' has no properties in common with type 'ServerOptions'

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am using typescript in my server and while I am familiar with typescript as I use it a lot I am not too used to it in the back end.
I am creating a socket I am also trying using es6 imports for because it helps with consistency. I am trying to change this:

```
require('dotenv').config({path: __dirname + '/.env'});
const app = require('express')();
const cors = require('cors');
const PORT = process.env.CHAT_PORT || 3000;
const ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const server = require('http').createServer(app, {origins: 'http://192.168.x.xx/'});
```

to this:

```js
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import * as express from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';
dotenv.config({path:'__dirname' + '/env'});
const app = express();
import http from 'http';
const server = http.createServer(app, {origins: 'http://192.168.x.xx:8100/'})
```

but with the second one where i have `const server = http.create(...)`
I get various errors like:

> Value of type 'Express' has no properties in common with type 'ServerOptions'.

as well as using types such as `const app: Express = express()` causes an import of Express from 'net'. 
while I love typescript it feel like a complete wrestle in the backend.

Comment: typo alert, is it really `'__dirname'+'/env'` or did you meant `__dirname+'/env'`?

Comment: @NinoFiliu yea it's a typo I want `__dirname + '/env'` without quotes on dirname but I've been changing a lot of stuff around so it might be with quotes. I'll wait once I start up my server and it complains haha

Answer (score 0):

Try using AMD modules, [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/amd-loader)'s an AMD loader for NodeJS. `npm i amd-loader -D`